# Need to implement nested try statements with one exception

Tags: python, try-catch

I am trying to copy a files from different folders under a path to my usb drive. 
So my source directory structure looks like this

/user/arun/Music/Songs/

under this I have different sub directories

Songs_1
Songs_2
Songs_3

the target folder is under anyone of these Songs directory

Songs_1/Kid Rock/All summer long.mp3 
Songs_2/Linkin Park/In the end.mp3

Now I am constructing my src_dir in a try/except way like this.

```
for album,song in song_database.iteritems():
    for s in song:
        try:
            src_dir_1 = src_dir + "/" + "Songs_1" + "/" + album + "/" + s + ".mp3"
            shutil.copy2(src_dir_1,dest_dir
            print src_dir_1
        except IOError:
            pass
        try:
            src_dir_1 = src_dir + "/" + "Songs_2" + "/" + album + "/" + s + ".mp3"
            shutil.copy2(src_dir_1,dest_dir)
            print src_dir_1
        except IOError:
            pass
        try:
            src_dir_1 = src_dir + "/" + "Songs_3" + "/" + album + "/" + s + ".mp3"
            shutil.copy2(src_dir_1,dest_dir)
            print src_dir_1
        except IOError:
            pass
        try:
            src_dir_1 = src_dir + "/" + "Songs_4" + "/" + album + "/" + s + ".mp3"
            shutil.copy2(src_dir_1,dest_dir)
            print src_dir_1
        except IOError:
            pass
```

Is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: Why would you want to ignore an IOError?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a loop would be better:

```
for album,song in song_database.iteritems():
    for s in song:
        for sdir in 'Songs_1', 'Songs_2', 'Songs_3':
            try:
                src_dir_1 = src_dir + "/" + sdir + "/" + album + "/" + s + ".mp3"
                shutil.copy2(src_dir_1,dest_dir)
                print src_dir_1
            except IOError:
                pass
```

And, perhaps you would want to add a `break` statement if you succeed in copying the source to the destination...

As a side note, you might want to use `os.path.join` instead:

```
src_dir_1 = os.path.join(src_dir, sdir, album, s + ".mp3")
```

Comment: When I see people not using the `os.path` package I cringe a bit